# How to remove date appearing on every page

Tags: header-footer, templates

I'm using a [template from a website](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/durham-university-thesis), and the month/year is appearing on every page in the main body of my dissertation. I can't seem to find the line where this feature is turned on, please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `format.tex` file, the following elements set the header/footer of the thesis:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%                      Your fancy heading                       %%%%%%
%%%%% For the final copy you need to remove '\bfseries\today' below %%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\chead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\today}}
```

The description mentions that you need to remove `\bfseries\today` if you want to get rid of the date. Alternatively, within `thesis.tex`, use

```
\input{format}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
```

This overrides `\rfoot` after it's been made in `format.tex` with an empty footer.

Comment: Hey Werner, I thought I could just include this as a comment instead of a new question; I was hoping you could tell me how I can remove the "Chapter" appearing at the start of every Chapter in this same template.